# jQuery how do i select img src inside href

Tags: jquery, siblings

i have simple html that looks like this :

```
<div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="kl_big.htm" id="turn-of-cloth-01_lg">
      <img src="images/galery/turn-of-cloth-01_lg.jpg"   width="110" height="90" />
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
    </div>
```

i have like 20 sets of this div with different ids , now the href id im gtting with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function (event){

        event.preventDefault();
        var linkID =$(this).attr("id"); 
    });
});
```

i dont know what is the img object id , but i need to get its src value . 
i tried with Jquery like this :

```
var imgSrcVal = $(this).siblings("img").attr("src");
```

but with out result ,  also tryied inside the click event but again with no results :

```
imgSrcVal = this.nextSibling.src;
```

what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the child image (inside the <a> tag)? In that case, you shoudn't use "siblings", but "children" instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<img>` is not a sibling, it's a child of the anchor.

Try this instead:

```
$('a').click(function (event){
    var linkID = $(this).attr("id"); 
    var imgSrcVal = $('img', this).attr("src");
    //alert(imgSrcVal);
    return false;
})
```

[Simple JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/consultcory/KLMhF/).

Answer (score 3):

The `img` is nested, so use `.find()` or `.children()`.

```
var imgSrcVal = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
```

- `.find()` looks looks through all descendants
- `.children()` looks only at direct descendants

---

Or with native DOM methods:

```
var imgSrcVal = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

The `[0]` is because `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like collection. So `[0]` gets the first element found.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want. The image is a child of the anchor tag, not a sibling.

```
  $('a').click(function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var linkID =$(this).attr("id"); 
         alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'))
    });
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wrs5L/)

Answer (score 2):

the `img` tag in that example is not a sibling of the `a` tag, it's a child. So to get the value of the `src` attribute, you'd do `$(this).children("img").attr("src")`